# JavaScript: Difference in hoisting for let, const?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

### Background

I have a functions that is responsible for generating a random number and making it available.

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(args) {
    let {
        min,
        max,
    } = args;

    let currNumber = genRandom(min, max);

    const genRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;

    const getNumber = () => currNumber;    

    return Object.freeze({
        getNumber
    });
};
```

### Problem

For a reason I don't understand, when I run this code with Node.js 7.8, I get the error that `genRandom is not defined`.

But if I change the code from:

```
let currNumber = genRandom(min, max);

const genRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
```

to:

```
const genRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;

let currNumber = genRandom(min, max);
```

then it works!

I don't understand why this happens. I thought that `const` and `let` were hoisted just like `var`, but this leads me to believe I am wrong.

### Question

Can someone explain me this behavior ?

Comment: one thing that `const` or `let` difference from `var` is that the variable is not accessible before declaration.

Comment: So, they are not hoisted to the top of the function, right ?

Comment: @tsh you might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: FYI, using `var` would cause a problem too.  The variable may exist because its definition is hoisted, but it does not have a value until the line of code that assigns it a value runs in the place you put it.  Now, if you used `function genRandom() {}` to define your local function, then the whole function definition would be hoisted.  So, this has nothing to do with `let`, `const` or ES6.  Assignments to any kind of variable are not hoisted.

Comment: @jfriend00: It would cause *a* problem, but a different one. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - OK, fine - a different error.  But, it wouldn't work even with `var` so this issue is really just a misunderstanding what is hoisted.  I never understand why people define functions in this type of context with `const fn = ...` instead of `function fn() {}`.

Comment: @jfriend00: Absolutely. On defining functions as constants: It has the advantage of making the identifier read-only, and some people (I'm not one of them) like *all* the code evaluated top-down rather than having hoisting...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I guess I find the world easier to comprehend if a function is available in a scope rather than only in a piece of a scope.  If I want to narrow the availability of a function, I can always create a smaller scope.  And, the only thing it could conflict with in that scope is my own code so I've never found a reason to worry about that.  Call me old school, but I don't find `const genRandom = (min, max) => ...` to be nearly as expressive, easy to read or understand as `function getRandom(min, max) {}` either.  I think people are misusing arrow functions as the cool new toy.

Comment: @jfriend00: :-) Well, they are the cool new toy. (Well, they were. Now `async`/`await` is the cool new toy...)

Comment: @jfriend00: Letting the exception (e.g., rejection) propagate isn't a bad thing, provided it is handled at some appropriate stage. But people have always tended to ignore error conditions. Recent changes will encourage people to handle them (but I bet many will do it in the wrong place, either too early or too late): Browsers are starting to report unhandled rejections as errors in the console, and soon NodeJS will terminate on them, exactly like an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that `const` or `let` difference from `var` is that the variable is not accessible before declaration.

Just checkout the specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations

> The variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated but **may not be accessed in any way until the variable’s *LexicalBinding* is evaluated**.

> **Syntax**
>
> *LexicalDeclaration*<sub>[In, Yield]</sub> :
>     *LetOrConst* *BindingList*<sub>[?In, ?Yield]</sub> ;
>
> *LetOrConst* :
>     **let**
>     **const**
>
> *BindingList*<sub>[In, Yield]</sub> :
>     *LexicalBinding*<sub>[?In, ?Yield]</sub>
>     *BindingList*<sub>[?In, ?Yield]</sub> , *LexicalBinding*<sub>[?In, ?Yield]</sub>
>
> *LexicalBinding*<sub>[In, Yield]</sub> :
>     *BindingIdentifier*<sub>[?Yield]</sub> *Initializer*<sub>[?In, ?Yield]</sub><sub>opt</sub>
>     BindingPattern<sub>[?Yield]</sub> *Initializer*<sub>[?In, ?Yield]</sub>

Answer (score 8):

> I thought that const and let were hoisted just like var, but this leads me to believe I am wrong.

Not really, `let` and `const` are indeed hoisted, or as I like to call it, *half*-hoisted. There are two big differences between `var foo` and `let foo`: Scope and initialization. You already know about the scope difference. The second one is that with `var foo`, both the *declaration* and the *initialization* (with `undefined`) of `foo` are hoisted. With `let`, only the *declaration* of `foo` is hoisted, not the *initialization*. `foo` is only *initialized* when the step-by-step execution of the code reaches the `let foo` statement. You can't use (read from or write to) an un-initialized identifier. This time during which you can't use the identifier is called the Temporal Dead Zone (TDZ).

Even with `var`, the initialization that's hoisted is the initialization with `undefined`, not the value on the right-hand side of the `=`:

```js
console.log(typeof foo); // "undefined"
foo();                   // TypeError: foo is not a function
var foo = () => {};
```

The change you've made, moving the declaration of `getRandom` up before the first use of it, is the correct thing to do. (Or use a function declaration, since the declaration as a whole [including the creation of the function] is hoisted.)

Let's look at this half-hoisting thing:

```js
let foo = "outer";
function x()
{
    console.log("...");
    let foo = "inner";
    console.log(foo);
}
x();
```

*(`let` and `const` have block scope, but I'm using a function because I'll be constrasting with `var` in a moment.)*

Within `x`, that inner `foo` can't be used until the `let foo` line. *But*, you can't access the outer `foo` above it; this fails:

```js
let foo = "outer";
function x()
{
    console.log(foo);    // ReferenceError: `foo` is not defined
    let foo = "inner";
    console.log(foo);
}
x();
```

That's the half-hoisting: The *declaration* of the inner `foo` is hoisted, but the variable isn't *initialized* until the `let foo` statement. That means you can't use `foo` at all (not even from a containing scope) above the `let foo` line. The inner `foo` shadows the outer `foo` throughout the function, but you can't use it until it's initialized. This is covered in [Let and Const Declarations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations) in the spec.

This is in constrast with `var`:

```js
var foo = "outer";
function x()
{
    console.log(foo);    // undefined
    var foo = "inner";
    console.log(foo);    // "inner"
}
x();
```

That runs just fine because both the declaration *and* the initialization of `foo` (with `undefined`) are hoisted to the top of the function. (After hoisting, the `var foo = "inner";` line becomes a simple assignment statement.) So the inner `foo` shadows the outer `foo` throughout, and is also accessible throughout, initially with its default value (`undefined`) and the later with `"inner"` (once that's been assigned to it).

Since the TDZ is temporal (related to time), not spatial (related to space or location within the scope), you can use an identifier created by `let` or `const` (or `class`) *above* its declaration, just not *before* its declaration. This fails because `getNumber` tries to access `theNumber` *before* it's initialized, while it's still in the TDZ:

```js
const getNumber = () => theNumber;

console.log(getNumber()); // ReferenceError

let theNumber = 42;
```

This works because `getNumber` accesses `theNumber` *after* it's initialized:

```js
const getNumber = () => theNumber;

let theNumber = 42;

console.log(getNumber()); // 42
```

Comment: very well written. thanks for explaining half hoisting